# C++ Microsoft Native Wifi Read and Store data in XML files

Tags: c++, xml, wifi

With MS native wifi in c++, anyone knows how to read and store collecting wireless data in XML files?

Comment: It seems pretty simple. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Are you talking about [Microsoft's Native Wifi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556(v=vs.85).aspx), or what?

Comment: No to Blender.
Yes to Andrejs.

Comment: What do you mean by "collecting wireless data"? Sniffer log?

Comment: Data from WlanGetAvailableNetworkList() and WlanGetNetworkBssList(), after WlanScan() call.

Comment: So what is your actual question? How to save data into XML?

Comment: Those lists seem easy enough to work with. It might help if you ask about some particular problem you're having.

Comment: I want only know if there's something in the library to do that.
If don't I'll save manually in xml.